# Display one ViewController inside another

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller

I need to show a `UINavigationController`, which will have a `TableView`, inside my root `UIViewController`. If that's impossible, I'd like to know how to split the window and show 2 `ViewController`s in it. I need something like the Facebook app, but vertically, like this:

```
| NavigationController|
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
|---------------------|
|                     |
| root ViewController |
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES sir you can do that...
suppose you have a viewcontroller that has a tableView inside it namely tableViewController
than you can create it like ...

```
TableViewController *tableViewController = [[[TableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];
UINavigationController *navigationController =
[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tableViewController];
[self.view addSubview:navigationController.view];
[navigationController release];
```

You just need to specify the size and place of the subViewController so that it fits right in place.. hoping this helps.

Comment: Except, `addSubview` needs a view as a parameter instead of a view controller.